# How to change the count scale of a ddply statement?

Tags: r, count, scale, plyr

I would like to change the count scale (I called it Aggregation) because until now the scale only has values like 2.5, 5.0, 7.5 and so on. But in fact, the results are only integers, i.e. 1,2,3,4. So, I want a scale representing this situation but I do not know how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
test_fifty <- xmlParse(fifty)
vc2 = as.numeric(test_fifty['//*[@name = "VertexConnectivity2"]', fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "result")])
number = as.numeric(test_fifty['//*[@name = "NumVNodesPerNet"]', fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "value")])
vc0 = as.numeric(test_fifty['//*[@name = "VertexConnectivity0"]', fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "result")])

df2 <- data.frame(number,vc2)
df0 <- data.frame(number,vc0)
qrange50 <- range(0,vc2,vc0)


df1_summary = ddply(
  df0,
  .(number, vc0),
  summarize,
  count=length(vc0)
)

p2 <-
ggplot(df1_summary, aes(number, vc0, size=count)) +   
  geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)) + scale_size_area("Aggregation") + xlab("Number of Virtual Vertices") + ylab("Vertex Connectivity") +
  ggtitle("Substrate Network Vertex Connectivity Aggregation (size = 50)")
```

Comment: Is your question about how to have the size scale on your ggplot appear only as integers?  If you could provide a small reproducible example that would help.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean. My scale Appendix now looks like this:  2.5  5.0  7.5  10.0 and so on. But there are no values in the plot which can take 2.5 or 7.5 or any other non integer value.